# SQL Server msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to publish some query results in the e-mail in a structured format. I'm using the `@body_format` as 'HTML'.

I want to do like:

```
   Declare @processed_rows int
   declare @Sourcetype varchar(100)

   select @sourcetype = (some SQL query) 
   select @processed_rows = (some SQL query) 

   exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @body='some HTML' ,
        @subject = 'IGD-DEVELOPMENT SERVER UPDATED',
        @profile_name = 'IGDMail',
        @recipients =  ' abhisheks@exzeo.com
```

When I'm executing `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`, I want to pass these variables in the `@body` argument of stored procedure and use them in the final email, please help to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to declare another variable to hold your HTML code:

```
DECLARE @HTML NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @HTML = 'SOME HTML HERE' + CAST(PROCESSED_ROWS AS VARCHAR) + 'SOME MORE HTML' + @SOURCETYPE

EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL 
@BODY = @HTML
, @BODY_FORMAT = 'HTML'
ETC.....
```

You get the idea...

Comment: Thanks for the help John